# tkinter python grid function doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

# row = Zeile
# Column = Spalte


root = Tk()

root.title("z")
root.geometry("1080x700")

top_left_corner = Label(root, text="Links oben", font =("arial", 12))
top_left_corner.grid(row=0, column=0)

top_right_corner = Label(root, text="rechts oben", font =("arial", 12))
top_right_corner.grid(row=0, column=10)


root.mainloop()
```

the top right corner thing is just next to the top left corner object, why? I am really new to tkinter

Comment: Because there is no widget between column one and column nine.

Comment: ok so i have to add empty widgets between them?

Comment: By default, a row has zero height and a column has zero width. When you place something (say...) at only at row 5 column 2, rows 0-4 are effectively invisible, as are columns 0 and 1. It's only when you put a widget in a cell, or when you use `rowconfigure` and/or `columnconfigure` that a row or column gets a non-zero size.

Comment: Yes you have to fill the other columns for column 9 to be in the 9th position. But if you looking to give some gap, you can use `padx=10` or `padx=(0,10)`

Comment: You can make column 10 to fill all the available horizontal space by adding `root.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)` and add `sticky="e"` in `top_right_corner.grid(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the columns between the widgets don't have anything in them so they don't take up space. you can fix it by using `grid_columnconfigure()` to set the weight of any column in between the two widgets to 1 so the widgets are pushed to the edges of the screen

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("z")
root.geometry("1080x700")

top_left_corner = Label(root, text="Links oben", font =("arial", 12))
top_left_corner.grid(row=0, column=0)

top_right_corner = Label(root, text="rechts oben", font =("arial", 12))
top_right_corner.grid(row=0, column=10)

root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)# add this line


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The rows and column in grid no not take any space if they are empty. Easiest thing to do is add a label(same color as background) inbetween them (column=1) with the required width (eg. width=10) to push the top_right_corner to the right.

The proper way to do it though is to use  column configure,

```
root.grid_columnconfigure(X, weight=1)
```

which sets a blank weight to column X.

Comment: There's no need to add a label. You can configure a column to have a minimum width.